# Terraform: Filter object from array inside resource

Tags: terraform

Again terraform issue with dynamic map of values.

What do I have for the start, one local variable:

```
locals {
  users_with_appId = [
  for user in var.users: user if user.app_id != null
  ]
}
```

Users variable:

```
users = [
  {
    userName    = "john.doe1"
    roles       = ["ORG_ADMIN"]
    profile_attributes = <<EOT
{
  "testParameter":"value"
}
EOT
    app_id = "test123"
  },
  {
    userName    = "john.doe2"
    roles       = ["ORG_ADMIN"]
    profile_attributes = null
    app_id = null
  },
  {
    userName    = "john.doe3"
    roles       = ["ORG_ADMIN"]
    profile_attributes = <<EOT
{
  "testParameter":"value"
}
EOT
    app_id = "test123"
  }
]
```

Okta user resource

```
# Users
resource "okta_user" "users" {
  count             = length(var.users)
  email             = "${var.users[count.index].userName}@example.com"
  login             = "${var.users[count.index].userName}@example.com"
  ...//the rest
}
```

and okta_app_user resource

```
resource "okta_app_user" "app_users" {
  count    = length(local.users_with_appId)
  app_id   = "${local.app_name_to_id_map[local.users_with_appId[count.index].app_id]}"
  user_id  = element([for user in okta_user.users: user if user.email == "${local.users_with_appId[count.index].userName}@example.com"], 0).id
  username = "${local.users_with_appId[count.index].userName}@example.com"
  profile = local.users_with_appId[count.index].profile_attributes
}
```

When I run `terraform apply` I got this error:

```
  Error: Error in function call
  
  on okta_user.tf line 34, in resource "okta_app_user" "app_users":
  34:   user_id  = element([for user in okta_user.users: user if user.email == "${local.users_with_appId[count.index].userName}@example.com"], 0).id
  |----------------
  | count.index is 0
  | local.users_with_appId is tuple with 2 elements
  | okta_user.users is tuple with 3 elements
  
  Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an empty
  list.
```

But as I can see:
`okta_user` contain 3 items

and `local.users_with_appId` contains 2 items (where app_is is not null so `john.doe1` and `john.doe3` entries)

also this one

```
  element([for user in okta_user.users: user if user.email == "${local.users_with_appId[count.index].userName}@example.com"], 0).id
```

so index 0 should return `john.doe1@example.com` from resource okta_user
and it should be equal to first (0) index of local variable `"${local.users_with_appId[count.index].userName}@example.com"`

Also in foreach loop im comparing to  `local.users_with_appId[count.index].userName` so why does it even bother about number of elements between `local.users_with_appId` vs `okta_user` ?

What do I miss ?

Comment: Your example `users` has `appId`, but your locals use `app_id`.

Comment: ALso id your `users` data fixed? It would be easier to have it in the map form, then list.

Comment: app_id fixed in the code (copy & paste & adjust typo). The issue is in with this assigning okta_app_uesr to user_id from okta_user resource based on this local variable :(

Comment: and cannot change this count to foreach loop because all users will be reindexed and removed from okta as I know and readded again if this what You meant

Comment: Can you check if you don't have any typo in the constructions of the emails?  Your element fails because it can't find matching emails in `user.email == "${local.users_with_appId[count.index].userName}@example.com"`.

Comment: How did it go? Did you manage to check?

Comment: Hey, Yeah I just wanted to type. The key is this
```user_id  = element([for user in okta_user.users: user if "${user.email}" == "${local.users_with_app_id[count.index].userName}@example.com"], 0).id
```

So instead 
`var.field == "something custom"` it should be
`"${var.field}" == "something custom"` it should be. So simple string == string comparison instead somethin == string

Comment: I see. If you don't mind, I can provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: Go ahead, I don't mind

Comment: Thanks. Answer provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by condition `user.email == "${local.users_with_appId[count.index].userName}@example.com"` not being satisfied. Consequently, `element` was erroring out due to trying to extract an element form an **empty list** in:

```
element([for user in okta_user.users: user if user.email == "${local.users_with_appId[count.index].userName}@example.com"], 0).id
```

The solution was to use

```
element([for user in okta_user.users: user if "${user.email}" == "${local.users_with_app_id[count.index].userName}@example.com"], 0).id
```